# Get EQCSS and Angular2+ working

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design

[EQCSS](https://elementqueries.com/) is a CSS element query engine. Do you guys know any way to make it work within Angular2+ components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is unopinionated about styles. Anything should just work. I've just created a sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bslbcs). Keep in mind the following:

- You can't use script tags in your component as angular is removing them for security reasons
- You have to call  EQCSS.load() yourself because  the script is loaded before angular bootstraps
- You can't insert EQCSS code in the CSS that you're  using with angular because it ensures that what you have there is valid CSS and EQCSS is not CSS :)
- You CAN use style tags in your components to specify your EQCSS code. Just make sure you understand that by using EQCSS you lose the  style encapsulation that angular offers out of the box

Comment: Thanks, awesome answer!